# Maltparser giving error in NLTK

Tags: python, linux, parsing, nlp, nltk

My COde is

```
from nltk.parse import malt
mp = malt.MaltParser(working_dir="/other/apps/maltparser-1.8.1",mco="engmalt.poly-1.7.mco",additional_java_args=['-Xmx1024m'])
print mp.raw_parse("Hello World")
```

And the error is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "malt.py", line 13, in <module>
    print mp.raw_parse("Hello World")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/malt.py", line 139, in raw_parse
    return self.parse(words, verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/malt.py", line 126, in parse
    return self.parse_sents([sentence], verbose)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/malt.py", line 114, in parse_sents
    return self.tagged_parse_sents(tagged_sentences, verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/malt.py", line 194, in tagged_parse_sents
    "code %d" % (' '.join(cmd), ret))
Exception: MaltParser parsing (java -Xmx1024m -jar /usr/local/bin/malt.jar -w /other/apps/maltparser-1.8.1 -c engmalt.poly-1.7.mco -i /other/apps/maltparser-1.8.1/malt_input.conlljOba1P -o /other/apps/maltparser-1.8.1/malt_output.conllPLcoTu -m parse) failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Which version of NLTK are you using? This issue has been fixed in the `develop` branch: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/944. Now, the right way to call MaltParser inside NLTK is like this: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L97

Comment: The reason for the java command to break in the previous version of NLTK MaltParser API was mainly because of the dependencies that malt requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MaltParser API in NLTK just had [a patch](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/944) that fixes and stabilizes the problems that it used to have:

- [How to use malt parser in python nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009330/how-to-use-malt-parser-in-python-nltk)
- [Malt Parser throwing class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091698/malt-parser-throwing-class-not-found-exception)
- [MaltParser Not Working in Python NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513187/maltparser-not-working-in-python-nltk)

Here's an example of how to use MaltParser API in NLTK:

```
# Upgrade your NLTK.
alvas@ubi:~$ cd ~
alvas@ubi:~$ pip install -U nltk

# Get the latest MaltParser and model
alvas@ubi:~$ wget http://maltparser.org/dist/maltparser-1.8.1.zip
alvas@ubi:~$ unzip maltparser-1.8.1.zip 
alvas@ubi:~$ wget http://www.maltparser.org/mco/english_parser/engmalt.poly-1.7.mco

# In python, now you can do this:
alvas@ubi:~$ python
>>> from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser
>>> mp = MaltParser('/home/alvas/maltparser-1.8.1', '/home/alvas/engmalt.poly-1.7.mco')
>>> sent1 = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas .'.split()
>>> print(mp.parse_one(sent1).tree())
(shot I (elephant an (in (pajamas my))) .)
```

(See [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/malt.py#L284) for more demo code or [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/f4c16c2f9c46cc42c9b68ae746832b622581c6b5/nltk/parse/malt.py#L354) for a more elaborated demo code)

---

Note that you can also use the export features and you can escape the usage of full path when initializing the `MaltParser` object. But you have to still tell the object what is the name of the parser directory and model filename to look for, e.g.

```
alvas@ubi:~$ export MALT_PARSER='/home/$UID/maltparser-1.8.1/'
alvas@ubi:~$ export MALT_MODEL='/home/$UID/engmalt.poly-1.7.mco' 
alvas@ubi:~$ python
>>> from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser
>>> mp = MaltParser('maltparser-1.8.1', 'engmalt.poly-1.7.mco')
>>> sent1 = 'I shot an elephant in my pajamas .'.split()
>>> print(mp.parse_one(sent1).tree())
(shot I (elephant an (in (pajamas my))) .)
```